# Cakephp error from Auth setup

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, installation

I'm following the Auth tutorial brought with CakePHP and I'm encountering a weird issue. Basically, I'm trying to set up auth when calling it from the components variable in the AppController file, instead of assigning the values in the beforeFilter action as the tutorial suggests. Right now my components variable looks like that:

```
public $components = array(
  'Acl',
  'Auth' => array(
    'authorize' => array(
      'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
    ),
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'display', 'action' => 'home')
    //)
  ),
  'Session'
);
```

When I try to run this code I get the error *Fatal error: Class 'AppController' not found in C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Controller\CakeErrorController.php on line 31*. The weird thing is that everything works fine if I just comment out the logoutRedirect line. Do you have any clue on what is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by run this code? Which action are you performing?

What I can see is, that you tried to use a "display" controller, which seems wrong to me. I guess you meant "controller" => "pages", "action" => "display", "home".

Comment: Hi, yeah the display is wrong, but I tried different ones, thanks for the note though. With run, I mean that I'm running the whole CakePHP app, but this specific part is giving me the error I'm talking about in the description. Opening any page results in an error, unless i comment out the logoutRedirect section.

Comment: I edited your post and commented out one ), don't know if its in your file, but maybe thats the reason.

Comment: What do your error and debug log say?